# How to change the road color in Google My Maps

Tags: google-maps, mymaps

Is there a way to change the road color in a *map* created with 
[Google My Maps](https://mymaps.google.com/)?
I want to make a screenshot of my map, but the color of all roads should be black.

I tried to change the `CSS` via browser plugin **Custom Style Script** for Firefox without success.

I found also https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com, but I think it doesn't help.

Is there an way to change the road color of a **Google My Map**?

Answer (score 18):

There is a work around to do this

1. create your route with all the points
2. export your map as KMZ
3. create a new map
4. import this KMZ file in a new layer
5. Select  "**individual styles**"

Now you suddenly can choose for the the option "**individual styles**" Click this option
Then click the the name of your route  and you can change the colors of the route

(In de picture I made a part of my route black)

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Easiest option:

1. Open your mymap in edit mode
2. In the legend, scroll down to where it says: Base Map
3. Press on the little arrow. That gives you styling options that you can use to take a simple screenshot. But you can't really customize those.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.